# Using environment variables in "VM options" and "Program arguments"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my project configuration in IDEA, I have the following text fields:

[image: Project configuration]

I would like to define some environment variables, and refer to them in the fields `"VM options"` and `"Program arguments"`.

I tried with the following definitions for environment variables:

```
MY_FOLDER=/some/random/path
MY_ARGUMENT=2
```

and then in `"VM options"` I entered:

-`Dfoo=$MY_FOLDER`

and in program arguments I entered

```
$MY_ARGUMENT foo bar
```

However, the environment variables **do not seem to be resolved** prior to calling my class, i.e. if I inspect `args[0]` in Java, it holds the string value `$MY_ARGUMENT`,  **not**  `2`.

Why? and how can I fix this?

Comment: try removing the space after -D

Comment: Removing the space after the -D will allow it to be passed in as a VM option. As far as program arguments you could just split the String[] argument in main by "=" and parse it that way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can access environment variables using the brace-enclosed environment variable syntax. Example:

VM options: `-Dfoo=${MY_ENV_VAR}`

[image: VM options]

`MY_ENV_VAR` environment variable will be expanded properly.

**Update:** tested in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 and still working.

Comment: I have just tested it in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 with Windows 10 and it is working perfectly.

Comment: [This is the code](https://gist.github.com/davidmigloz/994ccce422384700f9e82501ad0b469e) I've used to test it. In the output I can see my environment variable expanded properly.

Comment: Works in version 2018.1 on Linux.

Comment: This solution works for IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 CE on Windows 10. But after adding a new environment variable, I had to close all IntelliJ windows & reopen for it to reflect.

Answer (score 10):

$ENV_VAR$ will be resolved correctly.

Idea uses its own notation for environment variables, they should be denoted with two dollar signs on both sides.

Comment: Please add some more details.

Comment: That was not the case. It did not interpret it when sending as command args.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. But classic environment variables as in @David Miguel's answer work

Comment: Yes, it does work, read the official bug tracker here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85313 and see when it works and when it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

Environment variables are not the same thing as program arguments. If you want to pass program arguments then you would call

```
java MyMainClass /some/random/path 2
```

Then args[] would contain

```
0: /some/random/path
1: 2
```

Comment: Thanks Eric - I have updated the OP. I think there may have been some misunderstanding in what I was asking. Let me know if you think your answer still applies.

Comment: Looking at your update, your question is related to your command-line shell and is not java related. If you expect your shell to expand such variables try "echo $MY_ARGUMENT" and see what result you get in the shell.