# System Property for VM arguements in IntelliJ Idea 14

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 14, I intend use a environment Variable's value for a VM argument, but intelliJ doesn't seem to understand. It variable name as it is as String.

How to use Environment Variable for VM arguments in IntelliJ 14.(Refer Screenshot below for what I have already tried)

[image]

Thanks for the help and support

Comment: There's another unanswered question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558855/using-environment-variables-in-vm-options-and-program-arguments

Comment: And the IntelliJ reference that doesn't help (in case someone searches for it, hoping it does help): https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-application.html

Comment: @NickVolynkin I already the options mentioned in the thread with % both before and after, but it didn't work. Hence i attached the screenshot