# IntelliJ IDEA does not expand environment variables in Program arguments in Run Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Same in [Using environment variables in “VM options” and “Program arguments”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558855/using-environment-variables-in-vm-options-and-program-arguments), the environment variables cannot be used in Program arguments in the Run configuration. If I put **$VARIABLE** in the Program arguments (VARIABLE is configured in Environment variables in the Run configurations.

None works.

- $VARIABLE
- ${VARIABLE}
- $VARAIBLE$

Is this a bug?

### Environment

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218149) affecting user environment variables defined in the same configuration, it works for the system environment variables.