# Problem with using environment variables in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables

It is not possible to use regular env variables references in intellij:

Approach:

```
-Dvar=${ENV_VAR}
```

simply doesn't work when environment variable was added in the same run_configuration.

[env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRvPr.png)

Anyway to resolve the issue?

Comment: I used environment variables in IntelliJ and it worked perfectly. How did you add them?

Answer (score 1):

Found an solution among responses for other/similar question.
Turned out that Intellij is using different notation when using env variables defined in the same run configuration.

For env variables defined in the system you need to use:

```
-Dvar=${ENV_VAR}
```

but for env variables created in the same run configuration, you need to use:

```
-Dvar=$ENV_VAR$
```

Post that helped me to find a solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280595/3484423.